# UTF8 Encoding C# Webrequest

Tags: c#, post, utf-8, httpwebrequest, webrequest

i`m trying to make a webrequest and send a post data in Hebrew
but the server side get it like "?????" and not in hebrew.

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(MyserverClient.Url + Constants.TaskUpdatePropertyURL);
((HttpWebRequest)request).AllowAutoRedirect = false;
((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = true;

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;";
request.Headers.Add("Pragma: no-cache");
request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Cookie: {0}", Client.phpId));
    request.Headers.Add(string.Format("requesttoken: {0}", requestToken));

    string postData = "Some Non-english text";      
    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);                
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);               
    dataStream.Close();
}

    try{
     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
         Stream dataStream2 = response.GetResponseStream ();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream2);
                // Read the content. 
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    }
 return responseFromServer;

        }
```

as i was saying, for a non-english the server get the post data as "???? ???-??????? ????" but i should be "Some Non-english text"
any Suggestions??

Answer (score 5):

try something like this:

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Uri.EscapeDataString(string)`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will do the work: 
in hebrew,

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)
```

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work properly for me anymore VS 2017 .net4.5

Comment: @AltF4_ Yah, this post is from 2014, it's still may work for older versions